# Drawing a oval shape to represent a race track given data

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, visualization, data-processing

So I have data with 100s of dictionaries which include both X & Y values. These data represents the coords from the start of the race to the finish.

From this data, I have gotten the

```
MaxX, MaxY, MinX, MinY
```

to figure the barrier of where the oval shape will need to be built. Based on position of one person in the race, the results can be shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9XEX.png)

As you can see in the photo, all 4 (red) points using the variables above show the maximum part it can hit. The green dot represents the racer which I am trying to make a outter oval around and a inner oval within in.

**Other data shows others racers which I have not included to keep it simple however the variables provides the MAX and MIN of all data.**

The green dot must not go outside the outer oval or go in the inner oval.

The idea is to draw a race track. This is done using both python and matplotlib.

How the red dots are presented:

```
plt.grid()
plt.plot(minX,maxY,'ro')
plt.plot(maxX,minY,'ro')
plt.plot(minX,minY,'ro')
plt.plot(maxX,maxY,'ro')
```

How the race is being presented (the green dots):

```
for x in dicData:
    if x["I"][-2::] == "03":
        v = conversion(x["X"],x["Y"])
        plt.scatter(v[0], v[1], color = "green")
        plt.pause(0.01)
```

If statement checks for the data of a certain racer.

Data is converted to X and Y coords as data is from a GPS so lon and lan are given at first. This data is then drawn onto the graph.

Once I have managed to figure how to draw a race track, I will change to matplotlib animation. For now I have just done it in a loop.

I do not know the calculation nor what to do to create this type of shape. This is because it is going diagonal making it extremely hard for me.

EDIT:

IMG >>
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh3tD.png)

I have now managed to create what I have wanted thanks to Brock Brown!!

Comment: Your question is not really clear.  Do you want to draw an oval that is bounded by the rectangle MaxX, MaxY, MinX, MinY ?

Comment: yes and then a oval below the green dot

Comment: One question at a time, please.  So, does your drawing library not provide a method to draw an oval inside a bounding rectangle?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the windows API directly.  Here is the method you need https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-ellipse

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So you're trying to calculate the position of the end of the green dots as you travel clockwise? I'm not entirely sure where you're looking to place the red dot. Maybe a few more examples would help?

Comment: I have added a new picture. As you can see, I want to join the point of the light blue dot to the end of the outter convex hull which passes through the red dot.

Comment: I've added another example. The two points join but it doesnt connect to the edge. I cannot figure out how to calculate the closest x and y coords of the hull to to connect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the outside, you may be looking for a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). For the inside, you could probably shrink the hull around the center until it doesn't contain any points.

If the shape MUST be an oval, then you're looking at an optimization problem. You could try an [evolutionary algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_algorithm) maybe, using your conditions as a fitness function. The traits of the creatures should be the oval width and height, and the rotation of oval. The fitness function could be:
When calculating fitness for the outside oval - count the number of points inside the oval. If it's equal to the total number of points, then for every point add 1/distance_from_the_oval to the score.
When calculating fitness for the inside oval - count the number of points outside the oval. If it's equal to the total number of points, then add 1/distance_from_the_oval for each point to minimize the distance.

I might come back sometime tonight to take another look at this. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Will give it ago.

Comment: @SocketLearner1302 No problem. Actually looking at your image again (https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9XEX.png), I have a few more questions about this. Are you looking for more of a tic-tac shape instead of an oval shape? That's what I see the course as, like two parallel lines with half circles at the ends. Also, are you wanting to include the part that appears to be "off the tic-tac"? I'm talking about that bit of green line that connects to the red dot at the top left.

Comment: Hi brock brown. Thank you for all the help so far. I have made an edit to the post. Hope that helps! I have decided to use the convex hull however I am now trying to make it a bit bigger as well as now make the inner shape.

Comment: @SocketLearner1302 It's my pleasure dude. Here's something to get you started if you're trying to shrink or expand points around a center:
https://pastebin.com/UUJw59qX
Just take the center of your convex hull and figure out how much you need to shrink it by to get your center, make the factor larger than 1 if you want to expand the hull. To get the center of the hull, just take the mean of the points of the hull (...I think). Lmk how it turns out.

Comment: Thank you soo much for all the help. is there any chance you are able to help me with this last problem? I have added to the bottom